# jQuery Carousel Needed Please, ever use or see one you liked?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am looking for a simple jQuery carousel example(s) that does not require a plugin just standard jQuery. I just need to have a handful of images (5-10) to auto scroll horizontally. I've searched quite a bit without much success unfortunately so I seek the collective wisdom of StackOverFlow. Can anyone point me to some examples they have used or found useful?

Needs to work in IE6...

Kudos to anyone who can help or comment with ideas! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I like this one: http://jsfiddle.net/PvPXM/ it's fade in/out and I'm not to sure if it works in IE6 though :\ (btw IE6 is dead :P)

Comment: Thanks Joseph. IE6 is definitely not dead in China and I have to support that audience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer from Joseph that worked:

jsfiddle.net/PvPXM